# How to set Bottom Navigation Bar in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Can anyone help me, my bottom navigation bar looks like this:
[image]

I want to make it to look like this: [image]

Offcourse, with blue color.

My code is below: Thanks everyone!!

```
layout.xml
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/main_manu"
            app:itemBackground="@color/blue"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"

            />
```

Application.java

```
final BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case  R.id.action_pocetna:
                        new ListaVoznji.Home().execute();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_unos:
                        new ListaVoznji.Login().execute();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_pregled:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(ListaVoznji.this,ListaSvihVoznji.class);
                        intent2.putExtra("voznja",voznja);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_shutdown:
                        Intent homescreen=new Intent(ListaVoznji.this,LoginActivity.class);
                        log = 1;
                        homescreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(homescreen);
                        finish();
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: why the random lorem ipsum ?

Comment: Because beginners need to write more words about the problem, and here I have shown the problem in pictures

Comment: i don't think it's just a beginners thing, i think that rule applies to any questions but i could be wrong. but your question seems valid so no worries, perhaps in future just try to add _something_ of value instead, as others might not appreciate it as much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `background` attribute to change the whole background , and if you want to customize the item's text and icon color , you can do this by :
First create a drawable file name item_background , add to it the following lines :

```
<selector>  
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
 
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>  

</selector>
```

Then in your bottom navigation view add attributes `itemTextColor` & `itemIconTint` with the value `@drawable/item_background`

Answer (score 3):

Add `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` in your layout in botton navigation